# Popup not positioned correctly using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I had my popup working by using e.pageX/e.pageY, but then I noticed that if I clicked something near the right or bottom of my page, the popup went off the page. I [read](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1262/simplifying-dynamic-positioning-with-jquery-ui) about using position and how it would automatically adjust, but I must have something wrong. Can someone help me position my popup and keep it on the page if it goes off the page when it opens?

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cxpuem2x/2/) that illustrates what I am trying to do.

```
var hoverTimer;

var mouseOverText = "This is normally a looked up value. Hard-coded here so
I can illustrate the problem. I'd like the popup to show up to the right
 bottom of the mouse unless near the right or bottom of the page. I thought
 position automatically did that."

$(".lookup").hover(
    function (e) {
        hoverTimer = setTimeout(function () {
            showPopupText(e, mouseOverText, "#4aacc5");
        }, 100); // Changed wait time for fiddle.
    },

    function (e) {    // Supposed to clear the popup when the mouse moves
    away. Works on my laptop...not sure why not in fiddle, so not concerned
    about this.
        clearTimeout(hoverTimer);
});

function showPopupText(e, mouseOverText, bkgColor) {
    var html = '<div id="titlePopup" class="tooltip info" 
        style="background-color:' + bkgColor + '; ' + 'display: block;">' 
        + '<span id="temp">' + mouseOverText + '</span>' + '</div>';

    timerPopup = setTimeout(function () {
        $('div#titlePopup').remove();

        $('body').append(html);

        var htmlPopup = $("#titlePopup");

        $(htmlPopup).position({
            my: "right bottom",
            at: "right bottom",
            of: "event"  // Tried different values...none seem to work.
        });

    }, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have your block element on your page with a `display: none;` attribute. Then on your jquery function

```
$(".lookup").hover(function(){
    $("#yourBlockId").toggle();
}, function(){
   $("#yourBlockId").toggle();
})
```

As for where to put your block I would suggest right where you want it something like

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 100%;">
    <div id="yourBlockId" style="position: absolute; right: 0; display: none;">BLOCK CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Forgot to add the `display: none` on the block element

EDIT2: Ok I think I get what you are trying to do now, I think you need to calculate the width and height of your element before you show it. Something like this:

```
$(".lookup").hover(function(event){
    block = $("#titlePopup");
    height = block.height();
    width = block.width();
    maxHeight = $(window).height();
    maxWidth = $(window).width();
    posX = event.pageX;
    posY = event.pageY;
    if ((event.pageX + width) >= maxWidth)
        posX = maxWidth - width; //you can substract a little more just in case
    if ((event.pageY + height) >= maxHeight)
        posY = maxHeight - heigth;
    //Now you have the position where your element goes. You can continue with what you had
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do not think that quite answers what I want. I want the popup to be to the right/bottom of my mouse. If I clicked an element that is near the right/bottom of my page, I want the popup to be left/top...something that it looks like position is supposed to do.

Comment: I noticed in my question and comment that I said "clicked". I meant to say "hover". If I hover over the element.

Comment: You can also set a max width and height for your element and use those to calculate the max position it can have

Comment: Ok. I was hoping to use position, but I will give this a try and let you know.

Comment: block.height() or width are undefined. Still working it.

Comment: Is your #titlePopup existing on the page by the time you run the code? Don't add this if you are creating the block after it. Create your block on the html and make it display: none, then this will fix the position.